# Why doesn't a line passing through origin satisfy the 2 intercept form of the equation of a straight line?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, geometric-interpretation

The 2 intercept form of an equation of a straight line, is:

x/a + y/b = 1

Where, a and b are the x and y intercepts respectively. For a line passing through origin, these two intercepts will become 0, and hence the equation will be left unsatisfied.

So.. what does this mean?

Comment: It means the two-intercept form doesn't work when there's only one intercept.

Comment: Don't we have two intercepts? Both of them being 0?

Comment: That's one way to look at it, so then I can say that the two intercept form doesn't hold if the two intercepts coincide.  What's the difference?  It takes two points to determine a line.

Comment: Ah, makes perfect sense! Quite simple, really. Thank you :D!